# How do I resolve the "TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()" error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newbie to Python (I'm only 14), and I want to create a bubble sorter for a random list of integers.  The following is my code:

```
list = input("Please put in a random set of integers, in any order you like (unlimited range), separated by spaces:")
list = list.split()

indexcounter = 0


def sorter(list, indexcounter):
    for v in list:
        int(v)
    while indexcounter < len(list) - 1:
        if list[indexcounter] <= list[indexcounter + 1]:
            indexcounter += 1
        else:
            b = list[indexcounter + 1]
            list[indexcounter + 1] = list[indexcounter]
            list[indexcounter] = b
            indexcounter += 1
            print(list)

indexcounter2 = 0


def checker(list, indexcounter2):
    for v in list:
        int(v)
    while indexcounter2 <= len(list) - 1:
        if list[indexcounter2] < len(list) - 1:
            if int(list[indexcounter2]) <= list[indexcounter2 + 1]:
                indexcounter2 += 1
        elif int(list[indexcounter2]) == len(list) - 1:
            print("Process finished." + list)
        else:
            sorter(list, indexcounter2)

sorter(list, indexcounter)
checker(list, indexcounter2)
```

Basically, if one integer in the list is less than the one following it, I move on and check the same for the next value in the list.  If not, I replace the two items in the list with each other.  When that process is done, I call a "checker" function that sees if the list is in smallest to greatest order.  If it is, then I print the finished list.  If not, then I run the sorter function again.  This repeats itself all the way until the list is done.

However, I keep getting:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

error for the checker function.  How do I fix this?  Thanks in advance!

I realize this is not the most efficient sorter, but I just need to finish this project.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you are comparing a string to an int... you can't do that, they cannot be compared directly... convert one or both of the values to a compatible types and do your comparison... or provide a function to perform the conversion...

Comment: User inputs are received as strings in your `list`. Convert every element into an `int` and use those instead. Your `for v in list: int(v)` does not do this; it just throws the converted values away. You need to assign them.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

That Exception is most likely raised here:

```
int(list[indexcounter2]) <= list[indexcounter2 + 1]
```

If you are certain you will only be working with numbers you can change all elements in the list to `int`s by using the following after the call to `input`:

```
nums = list(map(int, values.split()))
```

This takes the `int` object and maps it to each value in `values.split`, if a value in `values.split` can't be converted to an `int` an Exception is going to be raised.

As you can see I'm not using the name `list` for the value received from `input` and *you shouldn't either*, `list` is a built-in object in `Python` and by assigning that name to another value you mask that built-in object. So change your first line to:

```
values = input("Please put in a random set of integers, in any order you like (unlimited range), separated by spaces:")
```